# How to avoid the top margin in these divs?

Tags: html, css

I need to display several divs inline.
Since all divs must have the same width of the viewport and
they must be in the same line, I'm using **white-space: nowrap**
in the container.

```css
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.container > div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <p></p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div>OPTION 2</div>
    <div>OPTION 3</div>
    <div>OPTION 4</div>
    <div>OPTION 5</div>
    <div>OPTION 6</div>
    <div>OPTION 7</div>
    <div>OPTION 8</div>
    <div>OPTION 9</div>
    <div>OPTION 10</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that only the first div is displayed correctly in the normal top
position. The other divs are shown with too much top margin. How can I prevent that?

I want all the divs are displayed in the same top position.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vertical align property for div

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container > div {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <p></p>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div>OPTION 2</div>
  <div>OPTION 3</div>
  <div>OPTION 4</div>
  <div>OPTION 5</div>
  <div>OPTION 6</div>
  <div>OPTION 7</div>
  <div>OPTION 8</div>
  <div>OPTION 9</div>
  <div>OPTION 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your rule

```css
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.container > div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <p></p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div>OPTION 2</div>
    <div>OPTION 3</div>
    <div>OPTION 4</div>
    <div>OPTION 5</div>
    <div>OPTION 6</div>
    <div>OPTION 7</div>
    <div>OPTION 8</div>
    <div>OPTION 9</div>
    <div>OPTION 10</div>
</div>
```